# Suggestion to execute rule expressions

Tags: c#-4.0, expression, rules, rule-engine, business-rules

We have a situation where the user will define some set of business rules or expressions. That will be look like,

```
if(riskvalue <= 100)  // condition
      notifyObservers() // action
      remarks = remarkshistory //expression
      if(allowedriskvalue <= riskvalue) //child condition
          do something   //can be expression or action
      else
          do some other thing 

else
     do some thing
```

We will plan to parse this and save it as a expression with it's type, like condition, expression and action.

We have some set of operands and functions that can be allowed in the rule definition.

Please suggest me some validation techniques to validate the rule definition.

And, I want suggestion that either,

- use **expression tree** to execute the rule expressions?
- use any **custom rule parser / evaluator**?
- build the logic in **dynamic class using code dom** and execute it?

Thanks in advance!!!